# Double For Loop Defining Variables

Tags: for-loop

I am using the alphahull package to look at species area distributions. My ultimate goal is to save 183 different scatterplots, each consisting of the same x-variable, alpha (1-25), and unique y-variables, alphaarea. I have already accomplished this with the inner loop, but the outer loop needs some work. The inner loop is finding the alphaarea for values of alpha 1-25. The outer loop should repeat this with each species and create a scatterplot for each, saved to a jpeg file. The variable alphaarea should have 183 different sets, each with 25 values.

```
alphaarea = numeric(0) 

for (s in 1:183) { #outer loop

results = numeric(0)

for (i in 1:25) { #inner loop

Ai_ahull<-ahull((coordinates(subset(data, data$Species==s))), alpha=i)

results[i] = areaahull(Ai_ahull)
}

alphaarea[s]<-results[1:25]

alphaval<-c(1:25)

jpeg(file = "C:/Users/Lab user/My Documents/...Graph1.jpeg")

plot(alphaval, alphaarea)

paste("Graph_", s, ".jpg", sep="") 
}
```

The error that I'm getting is that the alphaarea[1] corresponds to only 1 value. The alphaarea for each subsequent s does not exist. The goal is to have each alphaarea have a length of 25 and for there to be 183 of them. Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions on how to do this or finds an error in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two places in your code where it looks like you are trying to make a vector for storing results from analyses.  The way you are making them the vectors are only of length 1.

```
alphaarea = numeric(0)

results = numeric(0)
```

If you call `length(alphaarea)` you can see that it has a length 1.  Therefore each time your loop does its thing it overwrites the previous entry.

Try this instead

```
alphaarea = rep(NA,25)
```

Which produces a vector of "NA" values that has length of 25.  The first time you loop through your code results will be save in the 1st slot, the 2nd time it loops it will be stored in the 2nd slot, etc.

Also, your code

```
alphaarea[s]<-results[1:25]
```

Doesn't make sense.  It looks like you want alphaarea to be a 125 x 25 matrix.  Try making an empty matrix to hold your data like this:

```
alphaarea <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 183, ncol = 25,
       byrow = FALSE)
```

Then check the output to make sure it looks write.

```
head(alphaarea)
dim(alphaarea)
```

A handy way to check if your loop is running correctly is to call `browser()`, which will put you into R's debugging mode.  You then have to press enter for each piece of your code.  You can then also look at what the loops are producing at each stage using commands like head, dim, length, summary etc on your data objects, eg head(alaphaarea).  Or just in alphaarea to see what the object looks like.

Finally your jpeg saving code seems off.  You need to generate distinct file names, which I assume you are trying to do with paste.  What you probably should do is first build a name and assign it to an object, which you code almost does

```
jpeg_name <- paste("Graph_", s, ".jpg", sep="")
```

Then in your call to jpeg() use `file = jpeg_name`.  You can use paste() to add the path to the file name also, otherwise it will just save to whatever the working directory is that you are in.  You can check your working directory of course with `getwd()`.

jpeg(file = "C:/Users/Lab user/My Documents/...Graph1.jpeg")